# Getting references from regular intervals at regular intervals

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data as follows (simplified) in two worksheets on a document:

```
Sheet 1 data: A1=1 -- B1=(Blank) -- C1=(Blank) -- D1=2 -- E1=(Blank) -- F1=(Blank) -- G1=3
```

Sheet 2 data: is blank currently

What I want is to place the data from sheet one in same row but alternate columns

something like this

```
Sheet2: C3=1 -- D3= blank -- E3=2 -- F3=blank -- G3=3
```

What formula can be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy - paste special - transpose to transpose the data. **Since it's an irregular interval, you might need to only copy/paste one column at a time into the relative rows.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[images source here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/transpose-excel-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa/)